# Android crop image to store in database using rest api

Tags: android, rest, cropimage.net

I have a bunch of code that works fine when I'm not applying crop activity 
but i wanted to apply crop to the selected image and send it to server using Rest API

```
TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data",savedFileDestination);
initiateProgressDialog();
```

How to set cropped URI instead of `savedFileDestination` so that it takes cropped image path as file ?

Comment: Refer this link @Snehal Gongle:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121904/4906130, you will find croppedImageUri in Util.REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE

Comment: I'm actually using this library which gives me feature to crop the image and set the height and width of the image        compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'   so i don't have to give seperate code for GALLERY and Camera this lib does that work for me....

Comment: So my big Problem is i'm unable to set the croped image path which is 
      file:/data/user/0/com.snake.againimage/cache/cropped560934775.jpg something like this which gives me error as        E/Upload: file:/data/user/0/com.snake.againimage/cache/cropped560934775.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Have you added permissions regarding WRITE and READ external storage in manifest as well as runtime permission if you're using marshmallow version ?

Comment: Yes I have added both permissions inside mainfest and also run time permissions

Comment: Okay no problem, I am posting an answer, give it a try
I am also using the same lib to crop images. So let me know if you don't understand or find any issue

Comment: @Bhavnik i found the answer i posted my own answer thanks for the help...  the issue was because of the cache memory..Thanks ;-)

Comment: Glad you solved your issue.... Happy coding my friend

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to crop:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    Bitmap bm = null;

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}



public static int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For all your answers and comments I found my solution it was that i have to firstly store my croped image into a file diectory because the croped image stores in the cache memory and we need the file path and send the file path  to server to store it..... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**On click of camera**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File outPutFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Path of your custom directory);
                if (!outPutFile.exists()) {
                    outPutFile.mkdirs();
                }
                Uri capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile("Your app directory name" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".jpg", outPutFile));
                Logg.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Captured_Pic ===== " + Uri.fromFile(outPutFile));
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

**On click of Gallery**

```
CropImage.startPickImageActivity(HomeActivity.this);
```

**OnActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Util.REQUEST_CAMERA: // Camera request
                startCropImageActivity(capturedImageUri);
                break;

            case CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE: // Crop
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                try {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        resultUri = result.getUri();
                        mProfileView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(resultUri.toString())); // this is my imageview, where I'll set that cropped image Uri.
                    } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                        Exception error = result.getError();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE: // Gallery request
                try {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);
                    startCropImageActivity(selectedImageUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**This method will set property to cropping image tool according to your requirement**

```
private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
    CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setActivityMenuIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.app_blue))
            .setGuidelinesColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.app_blue))
            .setScaleType(CropImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)
            .setFixAspectRatio(true)
            .setBorderCornerColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.app_blue))
            .setBorderLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.app_blue))
            .start(this);
}
```